# how to access a image by localhost from same computer?

Tags: jquery, html, image

I made a program which is used to save a image locally and the url of this image is saved in the database. While retrieving the data from the database using ajax then it will give me the urls and I will append that urls with a div class the code of ajax is given below:-

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/v1/get-all-upload-image?sortBy=date",
        type: "GET",
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
            for (i= 0; i < response.response.data.length; i++){
                console.log(response.response.data[i])
                $(".images").html('<img src='+response.response.data[i].image_url+' alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">')
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The Image url be like

> http://localhost:8080/home/iron/go/uploads/xyz/themes/2018/12/4/1543924926ironman1537870116062544.jpg

This will show nothing but while I remove the `http://localhost:8080` then it will show the image. Can anybody please tell me why it is doing like that? And How I will access this image?

Comment: You should try put the image inside you project (assets dir), can you try it?

Comment: yes @DimitriusLachi I tried it but it not works while I remove the `http://localhost:8080` the it will show my image

Comment: Your console showing some error? Probably, the image path is not correct

Comment: @DimitriusLachi see what the console is saying  `GET http://localhost:8080/home/iron/go/uploads/xyz/themes/2018/12/4/1543926011rtx2qo8te1498751170626.jpg 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: the image is not inside your project directory

Comment: you mean to say that the path I'm giving is not right path?

Comment: Yes, but first, you should move (or duplicate) the image for you project patth, like: (if your project name is project1) `../project1/assets/images/image.jpg` and call this path `localhost:8000/assets/images/image.jpg`

Comment: You using some JS framework?

Comment: @DimitriusLachi Now it is showing `http://localhost:8080/api/bkblog-mvc/assets/uploads/xyz/themes/2018/12/4/1543927364time15378701398951290.jpg 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: You using some JS framework?

Comment: No at backend I'm using golang and at front end I'm using html and jquery

Comment: @DimitriusLachi I think for this there is an other http server which will be used to access the instatic urls

Answer (score 0):

You need a relative path to your image, base on the root of your server. For example, if you have a folder structur like the next:

```
/
└── home/
    └── iron/
        └── go/
            ├── uploads/
            └── index.html
```

Then, if your serving the content on `/home/iron/go` the url to the image is http://localhost:8080/uploads/xyz/themes/2018/12/4/1543924926ironman1537870116062544.jpg